# Monitor all NFC activity in Android

Tags: android, monitoring, nfc

Is it possible to monitor/capture all of the NFC activity which occurs in an Android device for a set period of time? Specifically, I want to be able to see all of the data which is being sent to and read from a tag by any application which may be using NFC at that time.

I have a rooted device and the set of developer tools, so I assume this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If by "possible" you mean "by writing your own ROM mod that contains the spying capability you are seeking, then installing that ROM mod on your rooted device", it is definitely possible. I will be mildly surprised if it is possible outside of that, unless NFC behavior was standardized in Linux somewhere.

Comment: Does such a ROM exist?

Comment: I doubt it, as the odds of anyone having your particular itch to scratch are not very good. That being said, that's a fine question to ask somewhere that specializes in Android ROM mods.